# Conversion from Curies to current of alpha particles

Tags: nuclear-physics, unit-conversion

Is the following conversion correct from microCuries to Amperes?

$\mu Ci=(1$x$10^{-6}Ci)$ x $(\frac{3.7x 10^{10}Bq}{Ci})$ x $(\frac{2e}{\alpha})$ x $(\frac{C}{e})$

Becquerels are $\frac{decays}{s}$ so the activity is $\frac{\alpha}{s}$

$\Longrightarrow(\frac{\alpha}{s})$ x $(\frac{eV}{\alpha})$ x $(\frac{Coulombs}{eV}) $ = $\frac{C}{s}$

Comment: It seems like $e$ in Your equation has unit of $eV$, which is not true.

Comment: Ok, then this cannot be the right conversion....thanks

Comment: There won't be no general formula because energy of alpha particles is different for each decaying nuclide.

Comment: I have since realized the units of Becquerels are not decays per second, but just $s^{-1}$:  "becquerel /bec·que·rel/ (bek″ĕ-rel´) a unit of radioactivity, defined as the quantity of a radionuclide that undergoes one decay per second (s−1). One curie equals 3.7 × 1010 becquerels. Abbreviated Bq."